# Type conversion with pointer C

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion

This is a question in my exam. I don't understand why the result of this program is: `0 0 ac 40` . Can everybody explain it to me?
And that answer is on Window. It is different with another operating system, like Linux or Mac? I also want to know about it.

Thank everybody.

```
int main ()
{
   float a = 5.375;
   char *p;
   
   p = (char*)&a;

   for(int i=0; i <= 3; i++)
      printf("%x ", (unsigned char)p[i]);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"This is a question in my exam."* !? :-( Do you have to know the internal representation of float? (There are still endianness...).

Comment: __Single-precision floating-point format__ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: You need to look into [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to understand it better

Comment: I am pretty sure that your teacher was explaining it. Probably you had more important things to do when he did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a C expert, but I understand this way: float variables are 4 bytes (usually, to make sure, you could call `sizeof(float)`), char are 1 byte. When you created a float, you allocated 4 bytes with the binary value equivalent to `5.375`. Then, you have created a char pointer to it - it would split the binary value.

What you had to do in this question:

- Find the value `5.375` in binary form (4 bytes, 32 bits)
- Split that value into each byte (8 bits each)
- Check the unsigned char value correspondent of each byte

I'm not completely sure if the result would be different from Windows or other systems - I would check if little-endians systems are different from big-endians doing the same process.

I hope this helps you understand it.

Comment: `sizeof(float)` and little-or-big Endian matter.

Comment: the result will vary based on the OS, but just in endianness - everything else should still conform to the IEEE754 standard.